# How can I move breadcrumb before main title on Magento 2

Tags: magento, magento2, breadcrumbs

I would like please your help. I am newbie on Magento 2 and still searching things. I would like to move breadcrumb before title (on category pages, product everywhere). I tried to change it on default.xml `<move element="page.main.title" destination="page.top" after="breadcrumbs"/>`

but with no luck.

Also i tried to do it from catalog_category_view.xml on vendor/magento/module-catalog/view/frontend/layout but no luck. Can anyone please guide me where can I find the order that is loading?

Can you please help? Thank you in advance

Comment: after updating any content in xml you need to run magento setup:upgrade commands. did you?

Comment: <move element="breadcrumbs" destination="page.main.title" before="-"/> use in your custom module not in magento default or vendor modules/files

Comment: Thank u @Naisapurushotham for you reply, yes i did upgrade but didn't change. Also place it on custom module but nothing. Also i check on incognito but nothing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this,

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>

<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
        <move element="page.main.title" destination="breadcrumbs" before="-" />
    </body>
</page>
```

Comment: Thank you @Jaydeep but i want the opposite i want first the breadcrumb and then the title

Comment: yeah, you need to use ```echo $block->getChildHtml('page.main.title');``` in everywhere of your breadcrumbs.phtml file
Just put that after breadcrumb code.

Comment: it worked!!!! thank you so muuuuuch. I spent hours searching it!!!

Answer (score 1):

One should not call a title from a breadcrumbs template as this breaks independence.

Instead simply move breadcrumbs on top of main.content container.

`<move element="breadcrumbs" destination="main.content" before="-"/>`

You can find more info on this at Magento official documentation here : [Magento 2 - Reorder recommendation units](https://devdocs.magento.com/recommendations/customize.html#reorder-recommendation-units)