# How can I move page title from cms page after breadcrumb on Magento2

Tags: magento2, breadcrumbs, magento-2.3, page-title

I would like to ask please a question. I am trying to move all the page titles from all pages after breadcrumb. I managed to do that to the products categories with the help from here [How can I move breadcrumb before main title on Magento 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59071117/how-can-i-move-breadcrumb-before-main-title-on-magento-2). 
On the catalog_category_view.xml I added
`<move element="page.main.title" destination="breadcrumbs" before="-" />`
and then on breascrumbs.phtml I added on the end 
`echo $block->getChildHtml('page.main.title');`

So I did it the same on default.html i added `<move element="page.main.title" destination="breadcrumbs" before="-" />` and then on every breascrumbs.phtml I added on the end echo 
`$block->getChildHtml('page.main.title');`

I upgraded it but nothing changes.
Can you please help me?

Comment: have you used catalog_category_view.xml in your theme or in custom extension?

Comment: Hello @Jinesh and thank you for your reply. I used it in the theme.

Comment: show me path of catalog_category_view.xml ?

Comment: It's app/design/frontend/Mgs/claue/Magento_Catalog/layout/catalog_category_view.xml but in the category it works I managed to do that with the <move element="page.main.title" destination="breadcrumbs" before="-" /> and echo on title on breadcrumbs.phtml.. I can't make it work on cms pages, checkout and in general. :/

Answer (score 0):

put code here

```
app/design/frontend/Mgs/claue/Magento_Theme/layout/default.xml

<move element="page.main.title" destination="breadcrumbs" before="-" />
```

Comment: can you send me default.xml?

Comment: Thank you @Jinesh again for replying. Where can I send it to you?

Comment: jscatoz@gmail.com

Comment: have you send it or not?